# how to get the query result from this website?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I want to get the stock data from the website (http://www.tdcc.com.tw/smWeb/QryStock.jsp) via perl WWW::Mechanize.
For example, get the data by the stock number: 2330.
The code below seems to POST data OK, but not get the response data like the Manual operation does.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $stockno= '2330';
my $scadate= '20160422'; 
my $mech=WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url='http://www.tdcc.com.tw/smWeb/QryStock.jsp';
$mech->get($url);
$mech->success or die $mech->response->status_line;
$mech->form_number(1);
$mech->field('SCA_DATE' => $scadate);
$mech->field('SqlMethod' => 'StockNo');
$mech->field('StockNo' => $stockno);
$mech->field('StockName'    => '');
$mech->field('sub'    => '查詢');
$mech->click_button('name' => 'sub');
$mech->success or die "post failed: ", $mech->response->status_line;
print $mech->response->status_line, "\n";
print $mech->response->content();
```

Comment: That looks okay to me. What is going wrong?

Comment: Please add a sample of the result/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the site uses JavaScript, which isn't supported by `WWW::Mechanize`

You should take a look at [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox), which uses a running copy of Firefox to provide a similar API to the basic `WWW::Mechanize`. You will need to install the [Mozrepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) plugin for Firefox for it to work properly